# "required" validator for p-calendar

Tags: angular, primeng

There is no required validator available for p-calendar control of PrimeNG:

```
<p-calendar formControlName="startDateControl" [minDate]="today" showIcon="true"></p-calendar>
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is. [PrimeNG Calendar Docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

[image: Required Attr Calendar]

> **[required]="true"**

When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

```
<p-calendar formControlName="startDateControl" [required]="true" [minDate]="today" showIcon="true"></p-calendar>
```

You can also specifiy it in reactive form as you've used `formControlName`.

```
this.calendarForm = this.fb.group({
   'startDateControl': [null, Validators.required] // <-- Like this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. if you read fully the [primeng document](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) then you can get it

```
required  | boolean  |  false   |   When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.
```

So you can use required directive for your calendar input.